# passing a value to WebUserControl for show in a lable

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrols

hi
i have a WebUserControl that have a lable for show message
how can i send a value to the lable from Page to my WebUserControl at runtime.

Comment: from the page means, you mean code behind file??

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind file of your control you can specify an attribute

```
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public String customType
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["customType"];
            return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["customType"] = value;
        }
    }
```

And after you can get this attribute to fill your label in the pageload with

```
mylabel.text = mycontrol.customType
```

In the asp page you specify the attribute (here is the 'customType'):

```
<wuc:ContSign customType="person" ID="ContSignPanel" runat="server" />
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.attributes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method in your user control such as

```
public void ShowMessage(string message)
{
   Label1.Text = message;
}
```

Label1 being the label control in user control. Now you can use the method from Page as and when you need it - for example,

```
protected void Page_Load(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl1.ShowMessage("Hello");
}
```

where MyUserControl1 is the name/ID of web user control put on the page.

Answer (score 0):

just make a property to get and set values for the lable in the user control

```
private string _labelmsg;
public string LableMsg
get
{
return _labelmsg;
}
set
{
_labelmsg=lblID.Text;
}
```

and then set in the aspx.cs page like
 `UserControlID.LabelMsg="Set Any Value";`